# Which Bernstein is behind "Bernstein's Connected Sets"?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, math-history

Steen and Seebach in "Counterexamples in Topology" give "Bernstein's Connected Sets" as item 124.

"Let $\{C_\alpha|\alpha\in [0,\Gamma)\}$ be the collection of all nodegenerate closed connected subsets of the Euclidean plane $\mathbb R^2$ well-ordered by $\Gamma$, the least ordinal equivalent to $c$, the cardinal of the continuum. We define by transfinite induction two nested sequences $\{A_\alpha\}_\alpha < \Gamma$ and $\{B_\alpha\}_\alpha < \Gamma$ such that $A_\alpha \cup B_\alpha = \varnothing$ for all pairs $\alpha, \beta$ ..." etc.

The question is: which Bernstein is this? I'm guessing Felix (as in Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein etc.) but I'm not completely certain it is. There are few citations for this construct. Hocking and Young mention it, I believe, but I can't access this directly and only see bits of it through the metaphorical keyhole of Google Books.

There's a F. Bernstein citation in the back of S&S: "Zur theorie der trigonometrische Reihe" which I've found originally appeared in Crelle (1907), but I haven't been able to see enough of it to see whether it actually *does* describe this space.

So, Felix Bernstein here? Or some other (perhaps Sergei)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is also the paper by Bernstein cited by Hocking & Young, who give the example on p.110. Steen & Seebach have a note to that item saying that the construction is due to Hocking & Young, who modified an idea of Bernstein. Bernstein’s paper is accessible [here](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN243919689_0132?tify=%7B%22view%22:%22info%22,%22pages%22:%5B274%5D%7D) [PDF].

Comment: D'oh! I never thought to consult the "Notes" section, I so rarely remember it's there. So it's a fair cop that it's Felix. Thanks, the question is answered.

Comment: @PrimeMover: My pleasure!

Comment: @Prime Mover: In a [5 February 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/sci.math/GCl-79BcPXM/sxp7dgz9zTYJ): *... although any Bernstein set in R is clearly totally disconnected, every Bernstein set in R^n for n > 1 is connected! Sierpinski [18] proved this in 1920. A proof can also be found in Hausdorff [10] (p. 202). A minor modification of the Bernstein construction (use nondegenerate closed connected sets in place of perfect sets) is shown to satisfy a slightly stronger type of connectivity in Hocking/Young [11] (p. 110) and Seebach/Steen [16] (Example #124, p. 142).*

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro Yes thank you, Hausdorff [10] appears to mean his "Set Theory", I've just got it off the shelf to check in the biblio of that, and indeed he references "Bernstein F."

Comment: I have some notes on Bernstein's paper that apparently I haven't Latex'ed for my use or posted anywhere (I've looked), so they're handwritten and buried somewhere. But my recollection is that Bernstein was trying to find the the "ultimate exceptional set" possible for a trigonometric series result. Any countable set would work, and he showed that uncountable sets also worked if they had the property of having no (nonempty) perfect subset. I believe shortly afterwards (at most 2 or 3 years I think) William H. Young showed that every set of the type **(continued)**

Comment: Bernstein was interested in was somewhat low in the Borel hierarchy (level 2 or 3), and at that time it was known that any such set, if uncountable, had to contain a perfect subset (a few years later, around 1916 or so, Hausdorff and Aleksandrov independently showed ALL Borel sets had this property), and therefore Bernstein's result, while correct, was vacuous since none of the types of sets he proved his theorem for (uncountable and having no perfect subset) could ever arise as an exceptional set for the trigonometric series problem he was studying. That is, he proved **(continued)**

Comment: "if $E$ has no perfect subset, then $E$ can be an exceptional set for a certain trig. series result", but it turns out that only at most countable sets have the property of having no perfect subset and being a possible exceptional set for the trig. series result. Therefore, Bernstein's result wound up not being a strengthening of the already known result that any countable set can be a possible exceptional set. Incidentally, I'm pretty sure Bernstein proved a lot of other results in his paper, and what I'm talking about is only one part of it --- at least, that is my recollection.

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro I will research this. I have taken note of your comments and put them safe to take a look when I come up for air from this current project. Thx.