# Properties of "Bernstein's Connected Sets"

Tags: general-topology

Example #124 of Steen/Seebach's *Counterexamples in Topology* and [S121 of $\pi$-base](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000121) is "Bernstein's Connected Set":

> Let $\{C_\alpha\ : \alpha<\mathfrak c\}$ be a well-ordering of the set of
> all closed, connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
> We shall define $A_\alpha$ and $B_\alpha$ such that
> $A_\alpha \cap B_\beta = \emptyset$ for all $\alpha, \beta<\mathfrak c$.
> First, let $A_0,B_0$ be distinct singletons in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
> Now, assuming $A_\beta,B_\beta$ are defined for all $\beta<\alpha$
> and $|\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}A_\beta\cup B_\beta|<\mathfrak c$,
> we may choose $A_\alpha=\{a_\alpha\}\cup\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}A_\beta$
> and $B_\alpha=\{b_\alpha\}\cup\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}B_\beta$ such that
> $a_\alpha,b_\alpha$ are distinct points in
> $C_\alpha\setminus\left(\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}A_\beta\cup B_\beta\right)$.
>
> Bertstein's connected set is $A=\bigcup_{\alpha<\mathfrak c}A_\alpha$
> with its subspace topology.

Unlike most *Counterexamples*, few properties of this space are established in the
text other than its
connectedness. Clearly the space is separable metrizable as it's a subspace of
$\mathbb R^2$. What other topological properties (covering properties? path connectedness? completion?) can be established about this space?

Comment: Since it doesn't contain any uncountable connected closed set, it's not path-connected or complete.

Comment: Related is [Which Bernstein is behind "Bernstein's Connected Sets"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3707405/13130) (see also my comments to Brian M. Scott's answer). For some other topological properties, see [A locally connected metric space of first category](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/830639/13130). For some general measure-theoretic issues, see my [5 February 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/GCl-79BcPXM/m/sxp7dgz9zTYJ) "Remarks on Bernstein sets" (an oversight in a couple of statements are corrected in a follow-up post in that sci.math thread).

Comment: The construction quoted cannot be right.  Singletons are closed and connected, so $C_\alpha$ could be a single point, and it would not be possible to choose distinct $a_\alpha$, $b_\alpha$.

Comment: That's what we have in pi-Base; I wonder if *Counterexamples* was more careful. I'm guessing that tossing in "nondegenerate" fixes things?

Comment: Yeah, we need connected sets with at least two points.  Such sets have continuum cardinality.  That's what makes the induction work up to cardinality $\mathfrak c$, showing that $|A|=\mathfrak c$.